# PHP - How to tell which dropdown triggered a submission when both are in the same form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have timekeeping report that prints out specified data based on the values of two date selection dropdown. They dropdowns are in the form:

```
< DD \/>< MM \/>< YYYY \/> to < DD \/>< MM \/>< YYYY \/>
```

They are currently in the same form, and each field looks approximately like this:

```
<select name="start_year" onchange="this.form.submit();"><?php
    for ($i = 2013; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
        if ($start_year == $i) {
            $sel = ' selected';
        } else {
            $sel = '';
        }
        echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
    }
?></select>
```

There is one for day, month, and year for the start and end of the range.
I want to have a check when one submits that is they change the start date, for example, to be after the end date that it will shunt the end date to start date + 2 weeks.

What I need to know is, if the two are in the same form, how can I tell which of these sets of dropdowns triggered the change so I can change the value of the *other* date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: every DOM event includes which element the event came from.

Comment: You can't tell this once you're on the server side. You would have add some kind of switch with the javascript that will send another variable which will indicate which of the select box triggered the submit.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to submit the form each time the user changes any select box. Actually you can't tell which date the user is trying to get, maybe he will change all 3 "start date" dropdowns, maybe only the day. So I would suggest not to "autopost", but put a button to submit the form.

Comment: - I am currently submitting to alter the dropdowns to have, for example, the correct maximum number of days for that month.

Answer (score 0):

Just call both directly using eg. `getElementById()`. Thanks to that you'll be able to submit form from every element without any problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I am new to web programming.